# Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer

Tags: android, hierarchy, viewer

I very much new to linux  and android
I tried installing android sdk with the help of a youtube video.
I installed android sdk - android 4.1 (API 16)
Then i installed eclipse 
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343

My os is  Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
After invoking eclipse and trying
help->Install New software and add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

After selecting Developer Tool -> Next, after some time i am getting the error message

*Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
  Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found*

I tried internet searches to solve this issue 
1. I tried http and https - Same error coming.
2. I am enabling all the available software sites before selecting the new software download - Same error coming, but after failure i am seeing some of the sites were disabled.
3. I tried installing using a local zip file /home/xxxx/Downloads/ADT-20.0.0.zip!/- still same error
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: you hav to update eclipse version

Answer (score 0):

you have to update eclipse version from same you checking for software update, use this link:
 `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6` in that you will find Eclipse SDK>Eclipse SDK and then try updating ADT again it will work.